# Using function keys for switching applications

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any way to use some of the function keys on the keyboard for switching to an application? For example, I want to use F5 key to switch to Google Chrome and F6 key to Firefox etc.

Just to be clear: I don't want to launch an application using those keys. I want to bring the already running application to the front (I don't care if they launch the application if they aren't already running. It's a plus, however not necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Custom Shortcuts.

Define a shortcut and assign a shortcut key. When you press that key, application will launch or will come to foreground - if already running.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this for Chromium - Emacs - Firefox, however the keys launch a new instance instead of switching to them. I am looking for a solution which works for at least these 3 programs.

Comment: I found out that `wmctrl` is the tool to do that.

Binding `wmctrl -a <window-title` to the function keys using the `Custom Shortcuts` section that you mentioned works as intended. Does not launch a new instance if a window matching that title isn't available, however that's ok.